# How do I embed live streaming (video) with my ruby(2.2.1) on rails(4) application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, video-streaming

I want to add a functionality which will enable live video streaming 
I am developing this in ROR 
Is there any gem for this ?
Is there any third party vendor which will be good to embed ?

Please help me with this if u have embedded live streaming video feature in your webapp.

Answer (score 0):

This is by far the best tool I've experienced. We have a client who does large scale events, in both real time and playback. This is their preferred vendor. http://www.haivision.com/

They have good documentation and their support is pretty solid too.

Comment: Do they provide apis to integrate in rails ?

Comment: @PromitNeogy, you can parse their iframe tag, and it works like a charm. Very light weight. It would look a little something like this: <iframe src="http://player.theplatform.com/p/wer23fadf/<%= stream.player_id %>/embed/select/media/<%= stream.media_public_id %>?form=html" frameBorder="0" seamless="seamless" allowFullScreen></iframe>